# hide fixed element at footer javascript

Tags: javascript, css-position, fixed

How can i **rewrite this script** to hide the fixed element at footer?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var navoffeset=$(".fixedElement2").offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollpos=$(window).scrollTop(); 
            if(scrollpos >=navoffeset){
                $(".fixedElement2").addClass("fixed2");
            }
            else{
                $(".fixedElement2").removeClass("fixed2");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

here my style

```
<style>
 .fixed2{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
 }
</style>
```

and division  is

```
<div class="fixedElement2"></div>
```

and footer division is

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: add css property bottom:0px;

Comment: What is your case to hide the element i.e. onClick, onScroll or something else?

Comment: on scroll, i waant to put some advertisement at the left side of website and i want to hide it when it reaches the footer

Comment: @dipak dude that's not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

**JS**

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {

      $('#footer').show();

      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("bottom!");
        $('#footer').hide();

      }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
  .footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="" style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;">

  <div id="footer" class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*The hardcoded script which worked for me was*

```
 <script>
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                     var navoffeset=$(".fixed2").offset().top;
                                     var navoffeset2= $('.footer').offset().top;
                                     var body = document.body;
                                     var bodyoffsetheight = body.offsetHeight; 
                                      //alert(bodyoffsetheight);
                                     $(window).scroll(function(){
                                         //alert(navoffeset2);
                                        var scrollpos=$(window).scrollTop(); 
                                    //  alert(scrollpos);
                                        if(scrollpos >navoffeset && scrollpos<1350){
                                            $(".fixedElement2").addClass("fixed2");
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $(".fixedElement2").removeClass("fixed2");
                                        }


                                     });

                                });

                            </script>
```